# How can I disable the Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: windows-7

The Credential Manager seems to be more trouble than it's worth.  How can I disable it?

Comment: How did it get in your way? It doesn't do much yet in Windows. It only keeps the password for a few MS programs and it seems to be the only API for those apps to store a password.

Comment: @billc.cn: Example: when I try to RDP to a Windows 7 desktop that has the CM enabled, it gives me an error.  So I have to add several steps to the RDP login procedure every time I connect, just to get around the CM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the Credential Manager that was causing the problems was part of the "HP ProtectTools Security Manager Suite".  Once I uninstalled that, along with all the other HP cruft that was pre-installed on this OEM box, the login problems disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly find the answer to the problem which produced this question...
How to disable the Windows Credential Manager,
'Run as' Admin:
Menu -> Accessories -> Administrator Tools -> Services (or Component Services then Services),
-> Services( Local )
 -> highlight Credential Manager -> Right-Click on, select properties, -> General tab,
 -> 'Startup type' in drop-down tab, ->select disabled.
Click 'Apply' then OK.

[image: image of prop cred services]

Backup by Exporting,
Services can be viewed in extended or standard - change view at the bottom.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open an administrator Command Prompt and type:

```
sc stop VaultSvc
```

Then you can even delete the service:

```
sc delete VaultSvc
```

Answer (score 0):

To Start Credential Manager write this on command prompt window:

net start VaultSvc

Note: You can’t start a service if Startup type is on Disabled.

To Stop Credential Manager:

net stop VaultSvc

To change Startup type:

Automatic:
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f

Manual:
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

Disabled:
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f

Automatic (Delayed Start):
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f

Note: When you change to Automatic (Delayed Start) a new key DelayedAutostart is created with value 1.
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

When you change to Automatic from Automatic (Delayed Start), DelayedAutostart change value to 0.
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VaultSvc" /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f